# Use of fork command in C in a chat application

Tags: c

I have a problem in this question, please anyone can guide me

Communication between client and server in C ubantu:

Client will send message and address of another client  to server and server will forward that message to that client. Other client will reply to server in a same format and server will forward that message to specified client.

I have to use fork command in this Question.

How I will send address to server and message together?

Comment: You will have two processes after the `fork()`; you'll need to use some form of IPC — Inter-process Communication.  Since you need to send addresses and messages around the place, you're likely to be using sockets.  You will need to read about how to set up sockets.  There are many relevant questions here on SO that will help.  Most of them involve a single client and a server; this appears to involve two clients and a server, but the two clients can be separate copies of the same program.

Comment: It also isn't clear that you'd be using fork in this scenario; normally, the server would run and the clients would connect independently.

Comment: fork is not related to sending and receiving messages together. Please ask a more specific question. Show code you already wrote, and indicate which place is giving you trouble.

Comment: actually its an assignment question and its requirement to do that using fork for 4 clients and 1 server

Comment: I think your teacher want you to use [pipe](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) to allow communication between process

Comment: the problem is how i will send address with message..... else communication between client and server have done

Comment: We don't have enough elements to help you on this point... If address haven't been defined, you have to define it. So use what is easier for you: client 1 have address 1, client 2 address 2, .... and create a structure like this `struct{ int address; struct message msg;};` which became your new message used to communicate through the pipe (encapsulate your message inside a new one which useful information for that level of transport)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use fork in this case. You can keep an array containing your client's sockets with a unique ID, which can be the address, and forward the message you receive from a client to the one with the ID specified in the original message. The select() system call can be useful when monitoring an array of file descriptors.

Comment: It's an educational question, so his teacher want to simulate client/server to illustrate use of some basic system API like `fork` and IPC. It's a common training, event if I agree with you terms "client/server" isn't relevant in this case

Comment: I agree - forking is a very bad idea in this case. If you want to read up on select() have a look at this excellent guide : [link](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select) . It helped me a lot.